# PHP login function not finding correct username and password

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication, pdo

```
    // query
     $result = $server->prepare("SELECT * FROM admins WHERE username= :hjnji AND password=     :asos");
     $result->bindParam(':hjnji', $user);
     $result->bindParam(':asos', $password);
     $result->execute();
     $rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
     if($rows > 0) {
     header("Location: database.php");
     }
```

I'm trying to create a login function, to my database to the table "admins". However, whenever I try to login into my database through a browser, it's echoing my error message that it doesn't have the correct username and password. I'd imagine it's something to do with my query not connecting to the database, but at the moment I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: Even though you're using prepared statements, you still have a security hole: your query makes it possible for the same username to exist with different passwords. It also runs foul of the problem that MySQL will do these string comparisons case-insensitive, which will be an additional problem if your passwords are clear-text.

A better approach is to search only for the username, and then check the (hashed) password field separately. It will also help with debugging why it's not finding the rows you need it to because it separates the two comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified, for one I'm not sure about the extra spaces in your query or the usage of "PDO::FETCH_NUM". I would propose the following.

```
$query = $server->prepare("SELECT * FROM admins WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
$query->execute(array($username, $password));

if($query->rowCount() == 1) {
    // Username / Password correct

    header("Location: database.php");
    exit();
} else {
    // Username / Password incorrect
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've added the simplified code into sublime and I'm still getting the error "please enter correct username and password" - this is driving me crazy. Do you have suggestions on what else could be coursing the error message?

Comment: Well the code wasn't perfect you need to change a few variable names ($username to $user). Hmmm, what's the DB structure look like ?

Comment: The DB is just a simple mysql database with two tables, admins and users. All the database has is first names, last names, emails and thats it for users -  admins has first name (username) and password. It's my first time using PHP, so please pardon my ignorance

Comment: Ok and how are you defining $username and $password ? Via $_POST['username'] and $_POST['password'] right ?

Comment: That's correct, yeah using $_POST. Just after post I have             if($user == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Please enter Username';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Please enter Password';
    $errflag = true;
} -- would this is all correct, right?

Comment: Are you sure that your table row names match up with the database row names, and also check the username and password you are using, you sure it's in the database ?

Comment: Man, I need to get my head around Stackoverflows formatting!

Comment: can you make a simple query? like select * from admin where id=1

Comment: Even a simple query isn't working, I'm guessing there is something wrong with the database?

Comment: Check the connection to the server ?